# Why such a small Krueger flap on 777-300?

Tags: aircraft-design, flaps, boeing-777, slats

Why is there such a small [Krueger flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krueger_flap) just inboard of the engine pylon on the Boeing 777-300, when the rest of the wing (including the further-inboard section of the wing) has [leading edge slats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading-edge_slat)?

I don't see an equivalent Krueger flap outboard of the pylon, <strike>unless there *is* one but can't be seen in this video</strike> There isn't a Krueger flap outboard of the pylon, according to [this image from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/A6-ECF_B777-300_Emirates_front_%284134226438%29.jpg).

Refer to [this video](https://youtu.be/MIzOX-Zz1HU?si=JfJEGeuQ7HvJTECb&t=155) (flap extension beginning at 2:35).

[image: Screenshot from the linked video]
Screenshot from the linked video with Krueger flap circled.

Comment: Notice how the fully-extended Krueger flap sits lower than the neighboring slats.  Here's another video example: https://youtu.be/RbZTYP0kGbE?si=dpsfDDHZG6cTty3u&t=937

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the slat–strut sealing; a photo from the other side shows the issue better *(images below).*

A normal slat would create a hole since the 777 engines are "close coupled"; this does **not** affect the lift (since there's a chine), but it affects the drag.

Boeing's solution to this is that tiny Krueger, which they call a "**Seal Krueger**" as it seals the hole, and with three engine manufacturers for the first generation 777, each manufacturer got a unique Krueger for a perfect fit.

---

**Source:**
Horse's mouth (Boeing's engineers):
- Nield, B. N. "An overview of the Boeing 777 high lift aerodynamic design." *The Aeronautical Journal* 99.989 (1995): 361-371. p. 367. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0001924000028670

---

Images:

> [image: hole]
> Nield, B. N.

> [image: other side]
> [Jerry Pang](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Japan-Airlines-JAL/Boeing-777-346/2339204)

Comment: The part about "each [engine] manufacturer had a unique Krueger [flap]" - interesting!  (But surely that adds complexity to the design and manufacture of this aircraft.)

Answer (score 7):

Due to wing sweep the engine nacelle blocks airflow that would feed a slot in that location, so the Kreuger flap is used instead. Outboard the pylon there is no such problem.

[image]

[ref](https://www.alamy.com/virgin-australia-boeing-777-aerial-view-at-sydney-international-airport-australian-airline-entering-voluntary-administration-aircraft-vh-voz-image354093607.html?imageid=2F44AE72-900C-4729-99EC-CCB8A23E0E0C&p=1262704&pn=1&searchId=df33a5870ab2bc7576751bc94e10213d&searchtype=0)